# Is there a way to import LinkToken, MockV3Aggregator, and all the other Chainlink mocks without adding the interface file?

Tags: python, openzeppelin, brownie, chainlink

I'm following the Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course lessons from Free Code Camp and I noticed that Patrick sometimes seems to import mock Chainlink aggregators and mock token contracts into his Python scripts from Brownie without adding the interface files.

My brownie-config.yaml file is configured the exact same as him, and I have all the proper information in the .env file. I attached an image of the error I see when I try to import interfaces the way he shows in the video. [This is the Github space](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/defi-stake-yield-brownie-freecode) of the project I'm following along with.[image]

For anyone trying to Google this exact same question, the error is as follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'LinkToken' from 'brownie'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all the imports were supposed to be in this test directory of the contracts. I should have realized by now that these are necessary when trying to run the scripts on local network.

[image]